# Substitute for `std::array::operator[]` in C++11 by using template-based recursion

Tags: c++, c++11, array, set

What follows is a simplified version of a tentative implementation for a template-based set, named `TemplateArgs`. For the sake of clarity and focus on the question at hand, `TemplateArgs` was converted into a non-parameterized class, and its size and elements are hard-coded. It should be C++11-compliant and portable (any OS, any compiler, any architecture, etc).

My question is about `std::array::operator[]`. Because it is non-`constexpr`, one needs to use `std::get()` instead to achieve `constexpr`-ness, unless a C++14 compiler is used.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

// Some recursion witchcraft
template <typename T, size_t size, size_t index = size - 1>
struct StdArrayContains_ {
    constexpr static inline bool contains(T elem, const std::array<T, size>& array) {
        return std::get<index>(array) == elem || StdArrayContains_<T, size, index - 1>::contains(elem, array);
    }
};
template <typename T, size_t size>
struct StdArrayContains_<T, size, 0> {
    constexpr static inline bool contains(T elem, const std::array<T, size>& array) {
        return std::get<0>(array) == elem;
    }
};

struct TemplateArgs {
    constexpr static size_t size = 4;

    // Some query/getter methods
    constexpr static std::array<int, size> values() {
        return {1, 2, 3, 4};
    }
    constexpr static bool contains(int elem) {
        return StdArrayContains_<int, size>::contains(elem, values());
    }

    // Some methods used for testing
    template <typename CharT, typename CharTraits>
    static inline std::basic_ostream<CharT, CharTraits>& 
    print(std::basic_ostream<CharT, CharTraits>& os) {
        os << "Size: " << size << std::endl;
        os << "Elements: {";
        const char* sep = "";
        for (auto& elem : values()) {
            os << sep << elem;
            sep = ", ";
        }
        os << "}" << std::endl;
        return os;
    }
    template <typename CharT, typename CharTraits>
    static inline std::basic_ostream<CharT, CharTraits>& 
    printContains(int elem, std::basic_ostream<CharT, CharTraits>& os) {
        os 
            << "Contains the element '" << elem << "'? "
            << contains(elem) << std::endl;
        return os;
    }
};

int main(void) {
    constexpr int validElem = 2, invalidElem = 5;

    static_assert( TemplateArgs::contains(validElem), "");
    static_assert(!TemplateArgs::contains(invalidElem), "");

    // Testing
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    TemplateArgs::printContains(validElem, std::cout);
    TemplateArgs::printContains(invalidElem, std::cout);
    TemplateArgs::print(std::cout);

    return 0;
}
```

The implementation works (compiles and executes without errors or warnings), but I'm wondering if I'm letting anything pass by, or if there is anything that's not allowed by the standard. For example:

- Is `TemplateArgs::contains()` truly `constexpr`? The argument to the function `elem` is not `constexpr` itself, but is being passed around in a lot of `constexpr` code.
- Is there any better option that's C++11-compliant (for example, implement a fully `constexpr std::array`, although I failed miserably at that)?

This is my system, by the way:

```
[flisboac@sonic ~]$ g++ -v && uname -a && lsb_release -a
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.2.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc-multilib/src/gcc/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-libmpx --with-system-zlib --with-isl --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libssp --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-plugin --enable-install-libiberty --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-multilib --disable-werror --enable-checking=release
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.2.1 20160830 (GCC) 
Linux sonic 4.8.13-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Dec 9 07:24:34 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
LSB Version:    1.4
Distributor ID: Arch
Description:    Arch Linux
Release:    rolling
Codename:   n/a
```

The whole template-based set's implementation is [here](https://gist.github.com/flisboac/fc34594cd54502fa462bd832085985ba), if anyone is curious to see.

Comment: Well, I think I actually found a better way to implement this functionality: https://gist.github.com/flisboac/fc34594cd54502fa462bd832085985ba#file-test-constexpr-elements-set-2-cpp